# Customize Laravel Passport response unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel-passport

Currently I have a login, register, update and delete functionality using my api made in Laravel using passport feature. Everything works fine the insertion of data and fetching the data from the database using this api. Now I wonder, how can I customize the response of the api when the token is expired. The expiration of token is working fine too. It automatically show this message

`{ "message": "Unauthenticated" }`

This is the code of routes where it is protected by my Oauth token where if the user did not login first then the user is not authenticated to browse the routes

```
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request){return $request->user();});



Route::post('/timekeeping','Auth\Api\AuthController@timekeeping');

Route::post('/login','Auth\Api\AuthController@login');

 Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {Route::post('/timekeeping_app','Auth\Api\AuthController@timekeeping_app');

Route::post('/logout','Auth\Api\AuthController@logout');

Route::post('/register','Auth\Api\AuthController@register');

Route::post('/show_dtr_list','Auth\Api\AuthController@show_dtr_list');

Route::post('/update','Auth\Api\AuthController@update');

Route::post('/delete','Auth\Api\AuthController@delete');

 });
```

Then this is how I response whenever the user successfully logged in, registered, or even logged out their accounts.

`return response(['status'=>'oK','message'=>'Successful!']);`

What I want is when everytime the user is using the expired token. The api should response something like this

`{ "message": "Token is expired" }`

not just

`{ "message": "Unathenticated" }`

Some threads discussed that I need to overwrite some functionalities of laravel but I don't know where and how am I going to start.

Comment: any updates on this situation?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I solved it. If you are using Laravel 5.5 or above you can override the default exception handler by editing `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        $json = [
            'isAuth'=>false,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
        return response()
            ->json($json, 401);
    }
    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);
    switch ($guard) {
        default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route($login));
}
```

In the JSON return, you can add any parameters per your requirement.

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Exceptions\array_get()

Comment: the important point is that in the request, we should have `Expect: application/json` in  the header. otherwise the `if` condition will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Add following at top of Handler.php file:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

And just add following function:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
   if ($request->expectsJson()){
       return response()->json(['message' => "Token is expired"], 401);
   }

   return parent::render($request, $exception); // TODO: Change theautogenerated stub
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me, found in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#protecting-routes).
You can override the unauthenticated function in the Handler like this:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

then, handle and provide the response you want.

Don't forget to import this as well in the Handle.php file:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

I hope it does work well for you!

Comment: This is just a pared down version of the already accepted answer from last year.

Answer (score 0):

Override `auth:api` middleware, and modify it accordingly to give the response you want.

Answer (score 0):

1- create new middleware UserAccessible

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserAccessible
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $isAuth = Auth::guard('api')->check();

        if(!$isAuth){
            // redirect page or error.

            $code = 401;

            $output = ['code' => $code,
                'status' => false,
                'msg' => 'Unauthenticated',
                'data' => []];

            return response()->json($output, $code);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2- Define middleware in Kernal.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'user_accessible' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserAccessible::class,
];
```

}

3- In Controller

```
class XController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('user_accessible');
    }
```

Or in routes

```
Route::middleware('user_accessible')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```